# I have stucked in the facebook server

Tags: facebook, authentication

I have created a website that allow user use facebook login system to regist and login. The system runs good. It can use single sign-on to login the system, so the user does not need to input the username and password --- until yesterday.

One of teammate find that he stucked in the login system, and the single sign-on does not function anymore. The user need to input account detail whatever they have login facebook or not. The most funny thing is, after the user login in facebook login system, it does not redirect the user to the "next" url or redirect them to facebook.com (mostly this means login system setting had eror). It just stuck in the facebook server with empty blank page.

This is the link what I stuck in....
https://www.facebook.com/login.php?login_attempt=1&fbconnect=1&display=page&next=(next url)&req_perms=publish_stream%2Cread_stream%2Cemail%2Cuser_photos&legacy_return=1

without session code, and does not have any reply.

I want to know if I have set something wrong...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use of legacy_return was deprecated almost a year ago with the migration to OAuth2, and the endpoints were finally shut down today. Please update your integration per https://developers.facebook.com/docs/concepts/login/

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Looks like I had to change my Login link into Login Dialog box.